# method overloading from parent class vs. overriding

Tags: java

if a method is overloaded, does it still inherit the original method from the parent class? What about overriding? Would it also inherit the original plus the overridden one?

Answer (score 5):

> if a method is overloaded, does it still inherit the original method
>   from the parent class?

Yes, you can use both of them.

> What about overriding? Would it also inherit the original plus the
>   overridden one?

Again - yes, but in this case to access the original method you'll have to use a call `super.originalMethod()`.

Answer (score 1):

> if a method is overloaded, does it still inherit the original method from the parent class?

yes.

> What about overriding?

yes, but the overidden method is not accessible to other classes.

> Would it also inherit the original plus the overridden one?

yes.

Answer (score 0):

In case of overloading, the method in the parent class is still available in the child class.

In case of overriding, the method doesn't run the parent's version unless explicitly called using `super.method()`.